# Setting axis scale to logarithmic in MuPAD

Tags: plot, mupad

I was wondering, is there a way to set the scale of the plot axis to logarithmic in MuPAD? This is possible with Matlab plots, but I couldn't find an option for MuPAD.

Answer (score 3):

**CoordinateType** attribute allows us to switch between linear and logarithmic plots.

By default CoordinateType is set to LinLin i.e. linear plots.
There are 3 cases of logarithmic 2d plots.

**Semilog Plots**

- **LinLog** - Linear coordinates are plotted along the horizontal axis, logarithmic coordinates along the vertical axis. Functions of form y = exp(c1*x+c2) become straight lines.

E.g. `plot(plot::Function2d(exp(x), x = 0 .. 100), CoordinateType = LinLog):`

[image]

- ***LogLin*** - Logarithmic coordinates are plotted along the horizontal axis, linear coordinates along the vertical axis. Functions of form y = c1 ln(x) + c2 become straight lines.
  E.g. `plot(plot::Function2d(5*log(10,x) + 8, x = 1 .. 100),CoordinateType = LogLin):`

[image]

**Logarithmic Plots**

- **LogLog** - Logarithmic coordinates are plotted along both axes. E.g. `plot(plot::Function2d(sqrt(5*x) + x^4, x = 10^(-3) .. 10^3), CoordinateType = LogLog):`

[image]

**Reference:[Coordinate Type](http://www.mathworks.in/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/coordinatetype.html)**